# Perl - how to use the reference id?

Tags: perl

When printing an object:

```
my $hash = {};
print($hash); # it outputs some sort of hex identifier: HASH(0X3A8154)
```

How can I use this hex identifier as a string or a key?

```
my $map = {};
my $object = {};
$map->{$object_id} = $object; # where $object_id is the string result of $object when printed
```

Comment: What you are getting is stringification of a reference (of a hashref in this case).  It's a string already. So you can just assign it

Comment: Is there anything wrong with just using `$object` as the hash key?

Comment: @SilvioMayolo Do you mean `$map->{$object} = $object;` uses a string as a key and object as the value?

Comment: Hash keys are always scalars, and all you have is a hash reference, which is also a scalar. (An object would be an instantiated class.) The hash reference will be stringified if you use it as a hash key.

Comment: @Matt Jacob thank you, I did not realize that before.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are getting is a stringification<sup>†</sup> of a reference, of a hash reference in this case.

So you get a string you want and can assign it to a variable (`my $id = "$hashref";`)

```
perl -wE'$hr = {a=>1, b=>2}; say $hr; $s = "$hr"; say $s'
```

prints `HASH(0x2398d48)` twice.

Then in the example with the hash reference (the "`$object`" – I'll call it `$hashref`) you can do

```
$map->{"$hashref"} = $hashref;
```

and in fact you can do

```
$map->{$hashref} = $hashref;
```

since the `$hashref` gets stringified in order to get a string needed for a key.

However, this does not seem like a good idea for general and common uses. For one thing, how can one distinguish the keys (always `HASH(num)`) to various `$hashref`s?  A key is used to identify the value associated with it and here there'll be some "random" numbers.

Why not come up with id's for your objects that are meaningful and carry information on their own?  You can also use a data structure that has `$hashref`s in it directly, since they are scalars. Or, better yet, write a class so `$hashrefs`s are *objects*; then you can set up any data/attributes you want.

Granted, I don't know how this fits in "*a distributed memory model*" where it's needed, and it surely is one way to tag a reference with an id unambiguously.

---

<sup>†</sup>  I can't find explanation of *stringification* in docs so can't offer a link.  See [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5214543/what-is-stringification-in-perl), for example

Comment: Although I could have used an id->object map and generated my own id, I thought this way was easier. Is there any particular downside? The main idea to create a distributed memory model and I needed a way to remotely reference objects.

Comment: @aoiee  I can't think of a very specific problem right now.  But, you _are_ creating a hash to keep track of `$object`s, so why not come up with some classification (id's) that carries more information, or meaning?  This way an `$object` is mapped to, well, itself in a sense.

Comment: I'm worried that if an 'object' is blessed to a function or perhaps other special cases, it won't be able to store an id as a property.

Comment: @aoiee  Hang on. You [bless](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/bless.html) things to make them actual objects of a class.  Then you can do all kinds of things to catalog/id them.  i don't understand "_able to store an id as a property_"?  For one thing, that's precisely what you can do if this is a class.

Comment: for example: `my @array = ('a', 'b'); $object_id = \@array;` wouldn't be able to hold an object_id property.

Comment: @aoiee  What do you mean by "_objectid property_"?  In that snippet the `$object_id` is an _array reference_. If you force its stringification, say by printing it or putting it under `""` and assigning to a variable, you get the string `ARRAY(...)`.

Comment: @aoiee  A note on references in case it is needed.  Forgive me if you know all this already.  A reference is a scalar, much like a pointer.  What you have in the question is a reference ("pointer") to a  hash, created by `{ .. }`.  What you have in the previous comment is a reference to an array, created by `\@ary` (another way to make a reference to something, by `\ `).  They don't make much sense to print or manipulate otherwise.  But if you do, they get converted to a string `HASH(...)` or `ARRAY(...)`.  Most things in Perl get "strignified" when needed.

Comment: @aoiee  An object, as an instantiation of a class, is a hash reference -- but that has been `bless`-ed, thus it "knows" what package (class) it belongs to. (One _can_ choose things other than a hashref for data when writing a class but it's seldom done.)  So when that gets stringified there is a bit more information put in the string, about the class.

Comment: @aoiee  Literature for references: tutorial [perlreftut](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlreftut.html) and reference [perlref](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlref.html) and data structurec cookbook [perldsc](http://perldoc.perl.org/perldsc.html).  For OO reference is [perlobj](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlobj.html) and tutorial [perlootut](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlootut.html).  There are of course many other resources.  Let me know if all this is unneeded and I'll remove these comments.

Comment: @aoiee  **Correction regarding "_they get converted to a string_"** in a comment above -- they don't, a string is generated while they of course stay what they are.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, it helped to explain how I can use the object as scalar hash key and how to force the stringification. However, I don't agree with the second part - to build a map of id's and have the object carry their own information. Although it depends on the situation, it is not always a possibility to store the id in the object.

Comment: @aoiee  Right, I don't really know how your application works.  I updated the commentary ("second part") to relax the statement. (But I do leave it, as a general comment -- please let me know if it's still disagreeable, too strong, or feels out of place.)

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use the identity of a reference as hash key, the correct approach is to use the [`Scalar::Util::refaddr` function](https://metacpan.org/pod/Scalar::Util#refaddr):

```
$map->{Scalar::Util::refaddr $object} = $object;
```

If you know that the object will not use operator overloading, it is sufficient to add zero:

```
$map->{0+$object} = $object;
```

---

Hash keys must always be strings. If you supply a reference or object as the key, it is automatically stringified first: `$hash{$x}` is the same as `$hash{"$x"}`. By default stringification uses a format like `HASH(0x1234abc)` for references and `SomeClass=HASH(0x1234abc)` for objects.

You can also coerce a reference to a number, e.g. by adding zero. By default this evaluates to the memory address/ID of the reference target.

```
my $ref = {};
my $obj = bless {} => 'SomeClass';

say sprintf "ref address: %x, stringify: %s", 0+$ref, "$ref";
say sprintf "obj address: %x, stringify: %s", 0+$obj, "$obj";
```

Example output:

```
ref address: 1990178, stringify: HASH(0x1990178)
obj address: 19903d0, stringify: SomeClass=HASH(0x19903d0)
```

This works fine until you have an object that overloads string or numeric operators:

```
BEGIN {
  package Freaky;

  sub new {
    my ($class) = @_;
    return bless {} => $class;
  }

  use overload
    fallback => 1,
    q("") => sub { "custom stringification" },
    q(0+) => sub { 32 };
}

my $freaky = Freaky->new;
say sprintf "freaky address: %x, stringify: %s", 0+$freaky, "$freaky";
```

Output:

```
freaky address: 20, stringify: custom stringification
```

So we can't use such an object as hash key directly. But we can side-step overloading.

- To get the default stringification for any value, use the `overload::StrVal()` function.
- To get the address of any reference without “tricks” like adding zero, use the `Scalar::Util::refaddr()` function.

```
use Scalar::Util;
use overload;

BEGIN {
  package Freaky;

  sub new {
    my ($class) = @_;
    return bless {} => $class;
  }

  use overload
    fallback => 1,
    q("") => sub { "custom stringification" },
    q(0+) => sub { 32 };
}

my $freaky = Freaky->new;
say sprintf "freaky address: %x, stringify: %s", 
    Scalar::Util::refaddr($freaky),
    overload::StrVal($freaky);
```

Example Output:

```
freaky address: 2203178, stringify: Freaky=HASH(0x2203178)
```